# curl not working and cant show the print_r data

Tags: php, curl

```
//   buat fungsi http request
 function http_request($url){

// persiapan curl
 $ch = curl_init();

//  set url
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

// fungsi transfer nilai yg berupa string
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// mematikan ssl verify dan peer verify untuk localhost (ganti valuenya bila sc ini berjalan di hosting
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

// tampung hasil ke dalam variable output
 $output = curl_exec($ch);

// tutup curl
 curl_close($ch);

//  mengembalikan hasil curl
 return $output;

   }

// panggil fungsi http_request (url / link api)
$data = http_request("https://indonesia-covid-19.mathdro.id/api/provinsi/");
$data = json_decode($data, TRUE);

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

why my curl is not working, what the problem? my machine? or my code?

i already try to restart apache, but the problem still persist, curl enabled btw

update:
im sorry, the last api service is currently down, but i already change it and the problem still persist, the problem is print_r print nothing, sorry if the question is less to understand, I am a beginner here

pls help me, thanks

Comment: _"why my curl is not working, what the problem? my machine? or my code?"_ - Before we can start helping you, you need to give us a proper description of what "not working" means. What actually happens? Wrong result? Error messages? Your computer catches fire? Have you checked the webservers error log? Have you checked what it returns before you do `json_decode()`? _"not working"_ can mean anything.

Comment: I don't know if the URL is the correct one, but when trying it in a browser, it times out.

Comment: sorry, the last api service is down, im already change it to new one, and the problem is print_r print nothing

Comment: Don't you have error log?

Comment: The posted code works perfectly fine when testing it with the updated URL. I get a proper output from `print_r($data)`

Comment: thanks, the problem was resolved yesterday, but I don't know what to do on Stackoverflow after the problem is resolved, the cause of error is I'm running php file directly on browser not via localhost and the current api is down

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your json_decode($data, TRUE); returns null. Please check that $data is a valid json string before you run this line `$data = json_decode($data, TRUE);`, otherwise it will return null, and print_r(null) will print nothing

Comment: We should hold off on writing answers until the OP has told us what happens. Right now, we have no clue what their actual issue is.

Comment: i think the url is correct json string, i already update it to new one, you can check it above